# Journey Builder Data Extension Update

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to create an Interaction in Journey Builder through the REST API which involves a Data Extension Update.  I am looking at the docs and they say to include the data extension id and the field id.  I cannot find the field id anywhere.  I was able to retrieve the interaction through the API and see that value after creating it through the canvas but for my use case this is not a viable option.

I am creating Data Extensions, Fire Events, Interactions, Emails and Triggered Sends all through the SOAP and REST APIs.  I do not have access to any of the generated ID's prior to creating everything above.

I tried just using the field name but that didn't seem to work.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to create this type of activity.

Thanks